# Is there any way to hide a column in a table?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am showing results in a `<table>` in a grid form. There is an ID column. Is there anyway through HTML or CSS that I can hide the first column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add the "display:none;" style to a `<col>` element corresponding to the column. If you want to show the column later, add an id to the `<col>`.

```
<table>
    <col id="x" style="display:none" />
    <col />
    <col />
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<script>
    function showColumn() {
        document.getElementById("x").style.display = "";
    }
</script>
```

Comment: As I've almost stated in my answer, this doesn't work cross-browser. A quick check confirms it doesn't work on Firefox and Chrome: http://jsbin.com/avega

Answer (score 5):

`<colgroup>` lookes promising, but in fact it doesn't allow too much CSS support - many CSS attrubutes simply don't apply with colgroup: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_colgroup.asp
Another option is advanced CSS selectors, like `+` or `:nth-child`, but they aren't supported by an older browser.
Your best bet is to add a class to that column, or to use JavaScript.

Answer (score 3):

```
tr > td:first-child { 
  display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you could apply css rule:

```
display: none;
```

[CSS display property](http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_class_display.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You could just not add that column to the HTML in the first place.